# Como permitir um campo DecimalField com o formato de moeda BR no Django?

Tags: django

Tenho a seguinte class:

```
class Carro(models.Model):    
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

E o seu respectivo form:

```
class CarroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Carro
        fields = ['valor']
```

Ao imprimir o formulário no template está aparecendo um *input* do tipo *number*:

```
<input id="id_valor" name="valor" step="0.01" type="number" value="0">
```

A questão é como permitir que esse campo aceite valores com ponto e virgula? Atualmente está aceitando apenas a separação do decimal (ex: 1253,00), gostaria que aceitasse separação dos milhares utilizando ponto (ex: 1.253,00). Qual a solução correta para este caso? A ideia é no input o valor vir no formato moeda (1.253,00) e no banco armazenar como decimal normal (1253.00).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que aceite ponto na separação do milhar basta colocar `localize=True` no field, no template o Django irá imprimir o *input* tipo *text*:

```
class CarroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    valor = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, localize=True)
    class Meta():
        model = Carro
        fields = ['valor']
```

Answer (score 1):

O que deu certo pra mim foi o seguinte:

*settings.py*

```
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

Função *__init__* do form

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SeuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['campo'].localize = True
    self.fields['campo'].widget.is_localized = True
```

Answer (score -3):

A solução do pedro também resolveu meu problema ao salvar.

Como estou usando agora, graças a solução passada aqui.

model.py

```
preco_servico = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
class ServicoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
        model = ServicoLi
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'nome': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'maxlength': 255,
                'placeholder': 'Digite o nome do servico'
            }),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'basic-url', 'aria-describedby': 'basic-addon3'}),
            'preco_servico': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'mask-money form-control',
                'maxlength': 500,
                'placeholder': '00,00'
            }),
    

        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServicoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['preco_servico'].localize = True
        self.fields['preco_servico'].widget.is_localized = True
```

e para finalizar estou usando um arquivo.js para mask, para o resultado ficar mais profissional na hora de digitar o valor.

```
$('.mask-money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
```

nessa solução não precisou usar o unmask(); no input, pois a função no forms dispensou essa necessidade.

o resultado funcionou em conjunto com a mask sem causar bug, sem precisar digitar virgula ou pontuação no valor, antes estava salvando com uns valores meio exagerados sem relação nenhuma com o que estava sendo digitado.

Funcionando perfeitamente no Django 3.2.7

Comment: O Stack Overflow não é um fórum ou grupo de debates. Somos um site de perguntas e respostas técnicas sobre linguagens de programação e esse espaço é exclusivo para a publicação de novas soluções pontuais a pergunta feita na página. Não use esse espaço para fazer agradecimentos ou discorrer sobre como uma das soluções o ajudou, aqui o agradecimento e narrativas aleatórias são considerados ruído. Para informar a comunidade da relevância de uma publicação temos um sistema de votações. Para conhecer mais do funcionamento do site veja a [help].